# What's the best practice for handling a controller that disconnects mid-game?

Tags: airconsole

I'm just looking to see the current best practice for it, not necessarily code. Do you let the game keep going? Do you stop where it's at?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that depends on the game play. If you have a game where it is extremely frustrating if you loose because of disconnects (like you have been playing a rogue-like for an hour) you probably should pause the game.

Of the 40 Games that we have in store, none pause the game, since it is very rare anyways and the game rounds are rather short.